# What is the Monero Messaging System Used for?

Tags: monero-messaging-system, mms

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4134

From the initial ticket, it states that the MMS is for making multi-sig easier. But why is it called a "messaging system"? I'm thinking from a lay person as if you can attach messages to your monero transactions, but its not. Also reading from the ticket, there seems to be the need of opening a new port: 18083

- What is the MMS and what potential use cases are there for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a messaging system for nodes to talk to each other which would make multi-sig less burdensome on users. Users would no longer need to transfer transaction files over email for example, they would let their node talk to the other node directly.

Comment: what other coin has this feature?